# How to get all the groups from a user in xmpp (using smack)

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to get from my contacts the groups they belongs to.I mean, I'll will have a list of contacts, and when I click on each contact, I'll show new list with their groups:

Example what I want:

*Contacts*

- UserA (onClick)
- UserB
- UserC
- UserD

*UserA Groups*

- Group1
- Group2
- Grpup3

It is possible to get all the user groups and not only the "shared"?

The project uses Smack library, and for obtaing my list of contacts I'm doing:(testing the results before implement the Adapter...etc..)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(RosterEntry entry : entries)
{

    builder.append(entry);
    builder.append("\n");
    Collection<RosterGroup> rGroup = entry.getGroups();
    builder.append("\t"+rGroup.toString());
    builder.append("\n");

}
Log.d("TEST", builder.toString());
```

And obtaining:

```
    02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Luis : luis@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Christopher : christopher@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Diego : diegom@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Fabio : fabio@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): testopen: testopen@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Diana: dianap@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Prova Prova: prova@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Jordi : jordic@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Rubén : rubenr@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): Mikel : mikel@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476): melissak@domain.com: melissak@domain.com [GROUPA]
02-03 14:31:28.421: D/TEST(22476):  [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6]
```

I know that most of the user are in more than 1 group, but I only can see `[GROUPA]` But I don't kwow how to obtain the others groups.

I tried to see what contains [org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup@36a55f6], but the only thing I achive is get again the same names, and not the groups of a contact

It's is possible to get it? How?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use Openfire server, then check the checkbox at admin console.

Users/Groups > Groups > GroupB(click) (at your case)

at Contact List Sharing box,

check the "Enable contact list group sharing"

maybe you can see other group name.